# Returning multiple rows postgres/ sql language

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem with the datatype and method you have to use to return multiple rows. I have a function in the database (stored procedure) that does the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
INNER JOIN some_table ON value = value
INNER JOIN some_tabl a ON value = value
INNER JOIN some_tabl ON value = value
WHERE table.id= 20
```

The output of this function gives 1:n rows. How do I return multiple rows? If a call the function like this:

```
SELECT * FROM functioname()
```

it will not work because I have to give columns names. When I try to make the function output parameters right in postgres it keeps giving me errors. Can someone help me with this? Much appreciated

Comment: Edit your question with the code you are using.  You seem to be confusing user defined functions and user defined stored procedures.  You cannot put a stored procedure into a query.

Comment: the code you are seeing IS the stored procedure

Comment: @user3464409 No, it is not. It's just a query. Start with the `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ...` part. Show the whole thing. Also show the **exact text of the error message(s)** and your PostgreSQL version please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[function vs stored procedure in postgresql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2357/what-are-the-differences-between-stored-procedures-and-stored-functions)

```
  create table test(a int, b varchar(50));
  create table test1(a int, b varchar(50));

  DROP FUNCTION some_function(in int);

  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_function(in int)
   RETURNS TABLE(a int, b character varying, c int, d character varying) AS
  $BODY$

  DECLARE
      some_input ALIAS FOR $1;


  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * from test a inner join test1 b on a.a = b.a where a.a = some_input;
  END$BODY$

   LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
   COST 100
   ROWS 1000;
  ALTER FUNCTION some_function(in int)
   OWNER TO postgres;
  COMMENT ON FUNCTION some_function(in int) IS 'FUNCTION JUST FOR TEST';

  SELECT * FROM some_function(1);
```

Comment: Given the context of the question, you might also explain the difference between a query and a stored procedure ;)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am sorry for that :)